# Removing Repeating text from csv

Tags: python, csv

The below code allow me to achieve this result but the

1. I want the file name and Type to be like the picture beside that only contain one.
2. Is there any ways to fix this problem?

[image][image]

```
if __name__ == '__main__': #start of program

master = Tk()
newDirRH = "C:/VSMPlots"
FileName = "J12312312" 
TypeName = "1234"
Field = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]
Court = [5,4,1,2,3,4,5,1,2,3]


newfile = newDirRH + "/Try1.csv"
with open(newfile, "wb") as csvfile:
    writer = csv.writer(csvfile)
    writer.writerow(["FileName", "TypeName", "field", "court"])
    for field, court in zip(Field, Court):
        writer.writerow([FileName, TypeName, field, court])
print "Done"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set `FileName`, `TypeName` to empty string after the first loop iteration.

```
...
for field, court in zip(Field, Court):
    writer.writerow([FileName, TypeName, field, court])
    FileName = TypeName = '' # <---
...
```